# Android GridView full screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview, android-relativelayout

I have a `GridView` and I use `BaseAdapter` to adapt images and texts in my `GridView`. I have one problem, when I run my app my `GridView' has left, right, top and bottom margins. I do not need these margins.

This is a my `xml` source:

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/strada_grid_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#d6d6d6"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:verticalSpacing="1dp" >

</GridView>
```

`GridView` adapter `xml` code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="#ffffff" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/desc1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/photo1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-27dp"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:textColor="#3d3b3b"
        android:textSize="12dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/stradaID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/desc1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/photo1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp" />
</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

How I can solve my problem?

Comment: Try to remove android:horizontalSpacing and  android:verticalSpacing from your gridview.

Comment: i removed it but nothink change.P.s i need there spacing

Comment: @PiYusH GuPtA no sir.

Comment: Also, why do you have a `RelativeLayout` inside another `RelativeLayout` that only has `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` and `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` as properties?

Comment: @user3863447 Show your adapter class and activity class.

Comment: thank you.i solved my problem.android:background="#d6d6d6"
    android:listSelector="#00000000" i wrote there and problem solved

Comment: ok then put that as an answer to your question and mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have set the default margin to 0 in the project location  **/res/values/dimens.xml** and it works for me.

< resources >

```
<dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">0dp</dimen>
<dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">0dp</dimen>
```

< /resources >

Answer (score 0):

```
   <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/strada_grid_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#d6d6d6"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="1dp" >
```

gridview adapter xml code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
```